# DBSCAN: What is a Core Point?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, dbscan

I have a question about [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

The points here are classified as *core points*, *border points* or *noise*.

- A point p is a core point if at least minPts points are within distance ε of it, and those points are said to be directly reachable from p. No points are directly reachable from a non-core point.
- A point q is reachable from p if there is a path p1, ..., pn with p1 = p and pn = q, where each pi+1 is directly reachable from pi (so all the points on the path must be core points, with the possible exception of q).
- All points not reachable from any other point are outlier

Consider the following image:

[image: DBSCAN example]

I don't understand, if there must be 4 points within a radius or a point needs to reach 4 another points, in order to be classified as a core point.
So consider the far right red point (just under the letter "e"). This is a core point. But within its radius are just 3 other points, not 4. So there should be 4 points within a radius **including** the one point itself?
There are just 3 other points reachable from that point.

Comment: The picture is the same as on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). There, the figure caption says that MinPts = 3. Could your MinPts = 4 simply be an error?

Comment: @StephanKolassa The figure caption on the Wiki page says minPts = 4. They might have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a database, all points are equal.

- The blue point has *1* point in its neighborhood - itself.
- The yellow points have *2* points in their neighborhood each.
- The red points have *4-5* points in their neighborhood each.

Note that the definitions don't say "minPts *other* points"; but "minPts points". You can't ignore the one point you already know (what if it has duplicates?)